# error: value < is not a member of sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File]

Tags: scala, sbt, aws-lambda

Trying to get sbt running with aws lambda and following this blog post about [Writing AWS Lambda Functions in Scala](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/writing-aws-lambda-functions-in-scala/).

I am starting off with having this in the `build.sbt` file:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "lambda-demo",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    retrieveManaged := true,
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0"
  )

mergeStrategy in assembly <
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

After `sbt compile` and I am getting this error:

> error: value < is not a member of sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File]
>   mergeStrategy in assembly <
>   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ^

What does this mean and how do we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been a copy-paste error somewhere along the process. It should be `:=`, not `<`.